# Spark Streaming - updateStateByKey and caching data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a problem with using updateStateByKey function and caching some big data at the same time. Here is a example.

Lets say I get data (lastname,age) from kafka. I want to keep actual age for every person so I use updateStateByKey. Also I want to know name of every person so I join output with external table (lastname,name) e.g. from Hive. Lets assume it's really big table, so I don't want to load it in every batch. And there's a problem.

All works well, when I load table in every batch, but when I try to cache table, StreamingContext doesn't start. I also tried to use registerTempTable and later join data with sql but i got the same error.

Seems like the problem is checkpoint needed by updateStateByKey. When I remove updateStateByKey and leave checkpoint i got error, but when I remove both it works.

Error I'm getting: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ueth8Zaj)

Here is code:

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# function to keep actual state     
def updateFunc(channel, actualChannel):
    if (actualChannel is None or not channel is None):
        try:
            actualChannel = channel[-1]
        except Exception:
            pass
    if channel is None:
        channel = actualChannel
    return actualChannel  

def splitFunc(row):
    row = row.strip()
    lname,age = row.split()
    return (lname,age)    


def createContext(brokers,topics):
    # some conf
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true").set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","false").\
    set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",'100')
    # create SparkContext
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    # create HiveContext
    sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

    # create Streaming Context
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

    # read big_df and cache (not work, Streaming Context not start)  
    big_df = sqlContext.sql('select lastname,name from `default`.`names`')
    big_df.cache().show(10)

    # join table
    def joinTable(time,rdd):
        if rdd.isEmpty()==False:
            df = HiveContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.getOrCreate()).createDataFrame(rdd,['lname','age'])

            # read big_df (work)
            #big_df = HiveContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.getOrCreate()).sql('select lastname,name from `default`.`names`')

            # join DMS
            df2 = df.join(big_df,df.lname == big_df.lastname,"left_outer")

            return df2.map(lambda row:row)

    # streaming
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topics], {'metadata.broker.list': brokers})        
    kvs.map(lambda (k,v): splitFunc(v)).updateStateByKey(updateFunc).transform(joinTable).pprint()

    return ssc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    appName="SparkCheckpointUpdateSate"
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: SparkCheckpointUpdateSate.py <broker_list> <topic>")
        exit(-1)

    brokers, topics = sys.argv[1:]

    # getOrCreate Context
    checkpoint = 'SparkCheckpoint/checkpoint'
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpoint,lambda: createContext(brokers,topics))

    # start streaming
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Can you tell me how to properly cache data when checkpoint is enabled? Maybe there is some workaround I don't know.

Spark ver. 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this working using lazily instantiated global instance of big_df. Something like that is done in [recoverable_network_wordcount.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/recoverable_network_wordcount.py)
.

```
def getBigDf():
    if ('bigdf' not in globals()):
        globals()['bigdf'] = HiveContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.getOrCreate()).sql('select lastname,name from `default`.`names`')
    return globals()['bigdf']

def createContext(brokers,topics):
    ...
    def joinTable(time,rdd):
        ...
        # read big_df (work)
        big_df = getBigDF()

        # join DMS
        df2 = df.join(big_df,df.lname == big_df.lastname,"left_outer")

        return df2.map(lambda row:row)
    ...
```

Seems like in streaming all data must be cached inside streaming processing, not before.